# Is there a way to get higher quality tiny text in java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an idle game based off elements and basic chemistry, and I was trying to get just a periodic table to show up. It's working so far, but the text of some of the element names are so tiny that it's becoming borderline unreadable. The code I'm using to determine the size of the text is this.

```
private void drawCenteredString(Graphics g, String text, int y) {
    //creates centered text for the element name
    int fontSize = (int)(size/5);
    String fontType = "Florett"; //font type
    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
    while(true){
        //tests if the width of the given text with the font type is larger than the
        //element square
        if(metrics.stringWidth(text) > (size-5)){
            //if it is, reduce the font size, and test again
            fontSize--;
            metrics = g.getFontMetrics(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
        } else{
            //if it's not, apply the font and break the loop
            g.setFont(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
            break;
        }
    }
    //this draws the text
    int x = ((int)(size/2)+this.x)-(metrics.stringWidth(text)/2);
    g.drawString(text, x, y);
}
```

[This is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh9KB.png)

I have been looking everywhere I could search, and I have found nothing on how to increase the quality of the text in java. I've seen people reach the same problem with `java.awt.Graphics2D` text, so I don't think switching to that would work better than `java.awt.Graphics`. Do any of you have any ideas? It's not too much of a problem, it's just a little annoying that you can barely read any of the large names.

I could also add a system that allows the element square to be enlarged when you hover over it, but that's a little impractical if you just want to get an overall view. Thank you to anyone that provides help.

**Edit:**
I have found a way to get around this (kinda). When you click on one of the squares, it enlarges it to be seen better.

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0OTk.png)

[Enlarged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1tyN.png)

This is not a very practical solution, but until I can find a way to get higher quality text to be displayed, this will have to work.

If anyone would like to make edits to my code, feel free to do so. Any help is greatly appreciated. You can also use this if you'd like to implement it into one of your projects, no need to credit me.

Runner.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Periodic Journey");
        Screen s = new Screen();
        fr.add(s);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.pack();
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Screen.java

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
public class Screen extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    Periodic_table[][] table;
    Periodic_table select;
    private int size, x, y;
    private boolean enlarge;
    public Screen(){
        addMouseListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        size = 64;
        x = 20;
        y = 20;
        int atomic_number = 1;
        table = new Periodic_table[9][18];
        //sets up periodic table (look at table for reference)
        for(int a = 0; a<table.length; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b<table[a].length; b++){
                //a is the y value, b is the x value
                int x = this.x+(size*b);
                int y = this.y+(size*a);
                if(a==0){
                    if(b>=1 && b<=16){
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, 0);
                    } else if(b==0 || b==17){
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, atomic_number);
                        atomic_number++;
                    }
                } else if(a==1 || a==2){
                    if(b>=2 && b<=11){
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, 0);
                    } else{
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, atomic_number);
                        atomic_number++;
                    }
                } else if(a==3 || a==4){
                    table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, atomic_number);
                    atomic_number++;
                }else if(a==5 || a==6){
                    if(b==2){
                        if(a==5){
                            table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, -1);
                            atomic_number = 72;
                        } else{
                            table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, -2);
                            atomic_number = 104;
                        }
                    } else{
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, atomic_number);
                        atomic_number++;
                    }
                } else if(a==7 || a==8){
                    if((b>=0 && b<2) || b==17){
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, 0);
                        if(a==7){
                            atomic_number = 57;
                        } else{
                            atomic_number = 89;
                        }
                    } else{
                        table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, atomic_number);
                        atomic_number++;
                    }
                } else{
                    table[a][b] = new Periodic_table(x, y, size, atomic_number);
                    atomic_number++;
                }
            }
        }
        select = new Periodic_table(0, 0, 0, 0);
        enlarge = false;
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(1200, 700);
        //this is the size of the window
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; //just here to set up for the future
        for(int a = 0; a<table.length; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b<table[a].length; b++){
                if(a>=0 && a<=8 && b>=0 && b<=17){
                    table[a][b].drawMe(g);
                }
            }
        }
        if(enlarge){
            select.drawMe(g);
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        int mouseX = (int)((e.getX()-this.x)/size);
        int mouseY = (int)((e.getY()-this.y)/size);
        int mx = mouseX*size;
        int my = mouseY*size;
        if(mouseX>=0 && mouseX<=17 && mouseY>=0 && mouseY<=8){
            if(table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber()!=0 && !enlarge && (mouseX!=2 || (mouseY!=5 && mouseY!=6))){
                int limit = 15;
                int otherLimit = 1200-limit;
                int otherLimitB = 700-limit;
                if(mx>=limit && (mx+(size*2))<=otherLimit && my>=limit && (my+(size*2)<=otherLimitB)){
                    select.enlarge(mx, my, (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if((mx+(size*2))>otherLimit && my<limit){
                    select.enlarge(otherLimit-(size*2), limit, (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if((mx+(size*2))>otherLimit && (my+(size*2))>otherLimitB){
                    select.enlarge(otherLimit-(size*2), otherLimitB-(size*2), (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if(mx<limit && (my+(size*2))>otherLimitB){
                    select.enlarge(limit, otherLimitB-(size*2), (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if(mx<limit && my<limit){
                    select.enlarge(limit, limit, (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if(mx<limit){
                    select.enlarge(limit, my, (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                }  else if((mx+(size*2))>otherLimit){
                    select.enlarge(otherLimit-(size*2), my, (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if(my<limit){
                    select.enlarge(mx, limit, (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                } else if((my+(size*2))>otherLimitB){
                    select.enlarge(mx, otherLimitB-(size*2), (size*2), table[mouseY][mouseX].getAtomicNumber());
                }
                enlarge = true;
            } else{
                enlarge = false;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

Periodic_table.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class Periodic_table{
    private Color alkaline_metal, alkaline_earth, transition_metal, basic_metal;
    private Color semimetal, nonmetal, halogen, noble_gas, lanthanide, actinide;
    private Color black, white;
    private String[] atomicList, valueList;
    private int x, y, atomic_number, size;
    private Font a_num, element, element_name, element_name_long;
    public Periodic_table(int x, int y, int size, int atomic_num){
        atomicList = new String[118]; //list of element names
        valueList = new String[118]; //list of element abbreviations
        setList(); //creates both lists
        atomic_number = atomic_num;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        int maxColor = 255;
        //sets the color for the different types of elements
        alkaline_metal = new Color(maxColor, 0, 0);
        alkaline_earth = new Color(maxColor, (int)(maxColor/2), 0);
        transition_metal = new Color(maxColor, maxColor, 0);
        basic_metal = new Color(0, maxColor, 0);
        semimetal = new Color(0, maxColor, maxColor);
        nonmetal = new Color((int)(maxColor/4), (int)(maxColor/4), maxColor);
        halogen = new Color(maxColor, 0, maxColor);
        noble_gas = new Color((int)(maxColor/2), 0, maxColor);
        lanthanide = new Color(maxColor, (int)(maxColor/2), maxColor);
        actinide = new Color(maxColor, (int)(maxColor/4), (int)((maxColor/4)*3));
    }
    public void drawMe(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        BasicStroke w1 = new BasicStroke(1);
        BasicStroke w2 = new BasicStroke(2);
        if(atomic_number!=0){ //tests if the square is empty (atomic number is 0 if it's empty)
            //draws the color of the element type
            if(atomic_number == 3 || atomic_number == 11 || atomic_number == 19 || atomic_number == 37 || atomic_number == 55 || atomic_number == 87){
                g.setColor(alkaline_metal);
            } else if(atomic_number == 4 || atomic_number == 12 || atomic_number == 20 || atomic_number == 38 || atomic_number == 56 || atomic_number == 88){
                g.setColor(alkaline_earth);
            } else if((atomic_number >= 21 && atomic_number <= 30) || (atomic_number >= 39 && atomic_number <=48) || (atomic_number >= 72 && atomic_number <=80) || (atomic_number >= 104 && atomic_number <= 112)){
                g.setColor(transition_metal);
            } else if(atomic_number == 5 || atomic_number == 14 || atomic_number == 32 || atomic_number == 33 || atomic_number == 51 || atomic_number == 52 || atomic_number == 84){
                g.setColor(semimetal);
            } else if(atomic_number == 1 || (atomic_number>=6 && atomic_number<=8) || atomic_number == 15 || atomic_number == 16 || atomic_number == 34){
                g.setColor(nonmetal);
            } else if(atomic_number == 13 || atomic_number == 31 || atomic_number == 49 || atomic_number == 50 || (atomic_number >= 81 && atomic_number <=83) || (atomic_number >= 113 && atomic_number <= 116)){
                g.setColor(basic_metal);
            } else if(atomic_number == 9 || atomic_number == 17 || atomic_number == 35 || atomic_number == 53 || atomic_number == 85 || atomic_number == 117){
                g.setColor(halogen);
            } else if(atomic_number == 2 || atomic_number == 10 || atomic_number == 18 || atomic_number == 36 || atomic_number == 54 || atomic_number == 86 || atomic_number == 118){
                g.setColor(noble_gas);
            } else if((atomic_number >= 57 && atomic_number <= 71) || atomic_number == -1){
                g.setColor(lanthanide);
            } else if((atomic_number >= 89 && atomic_number <= 103) || atomic_number == -2){
                g.setColor(actinide);
            }
            g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
            g2.setStroke(w2);
            g.setColor(black);
            g.drawRect(x, y, size, size);
            g2.setStroke(w1);
            //draws the text
            if(atomic_number>0){
                g.setFont(new Font("Florett", Font.BOLD, (int)(size/5)));
                g.drawString(atomic_number + "", x+((int)(size/16)), y+((int)(size/4)));
                drawCenteredString(g, valueList[atomic_number-1]);
                drawCenteredString(g, atomicList[atomic_number-1], y+(size-((int)(size/8))));
                g.setColor(black);
            } else if(atomic_number==-1){
                drawCenteredString(g, "Lanthanides");
                g.setFont(new Font("Florett", Font.BOLD, (int)(size/5)));
                g.drawString("57-71", x+((int)(size/16)), y+((int)(size/4)));
            } else if(atomic_number==-2){
                drawCenteredString(g, "Actinides");
                g.setFont(new Font("Florett", Font.BOLD, (int)(size/5)));
                g.drawString("89-103", x+((int)(size/16)), y+((int)(size/4)));
            }
        }
    }
    private void drawCenteredString(Graphics g, String text) {
        //creates centered text for the element abbreviation
        int fontSize = (int)(size/3);
        String fontType = "Florett";
        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
        while(true){
            //tests if the width of the given text with the font type is larger than the
            //element square
            if(metrics.stringWidth(text) > (size-5)){
                //if it is, reduce the font size, and test again
                fontSize--;
                metrics = g.getFontMetrics(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
            } else{
                //if it's not, apply the font and break the loop
                g.setFont(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
                break;
            }
        }
        int x = ((int)(size/2)+this.x)-(metrics.stringWidth(text)/2);
        int y = (((int)(size/2)+this.y)-(metrics.getHeight()/2)) + metrics.getAscent();
        g.setFont(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
        g.drawString(text, x, y);
    }
    private void drawCenteredString(Graphics g, String text, int y) {
        //creates centered text for the element name
        int fontSize = (int)(size/5);
        String fontType = "Florett"; //font type
        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
        while(true){
            //tests if the width of the given text with the font type is larger than the
            //element square
            if(metrics.stringWidth(text) > (size-5)){
                //if it is, reduce the font size, and test again
                fontSize--;
                metrics = g.getFontMetrics(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
            } else{
                //if it's not, apply the font and break the loop
                g.setFont(new Font(fontType, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
                break;
            }
        }
        //this draws the text
        int x = ((int)(size/2)+this.x)-(metrics.stringWidth(text)/2);
        g.drawString(text, x, y);
    }
    public int getAtomicNumber(){
        return atomic_number;
    }
    public void enlarge(int x, int y, int size, int atomic_num){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        atomic_number = atomic_num;
    }
    private void setList(){
        //sets up both lists
        atomicList[0] = "Hydrogen";
        valueList[0] = "H";
        atomicList[1] = "Helium";
        valueList[1] = "He";
        atomicList[2] = "Lithium";
        valueList[2] = "Li";
        atomicList[3] = "Beryllium";
        valueList[3] = "Be";
        atomicList[4] = "Boron";
        valueList[4] = "B";
        atomicList[5] = "Carbon";
        valueList[5] = "C";
        atomicList[6] = "Nitrogen";
        valueList[6] = "N";
        atomicList[7] = "Oxygen";
        valueList[7] = "O";
        atomicList[8] = "Fluorine";
        valueList[8] = "F";
        atomicList[9] = "Neon";
        valueList[9] = "Ne";
        atomicList[10] = "Sodium";
        valueList[10] = "Na";
        atomicList[11] = "Magnesium";
        valueList[11] = "Mg";
        atomicList[12] = "Aluminum";
        valueList[12] = "Al";
        atomicList[13] = "Silicon";
        valueList[13] = "Si";
        atomicList[14] = "Phosphorus";
        valueList[14] = "P";
        atomicList[15] = "Sulfur";
        valueList[15] = "S";
        atomicList[16] = "Chlorine";
        valueList[16] = "Cl";
        atomicList[17] = "Argon";
        valueList[17] = "Ar";
        atomicList[18] = "Potassium";
        valueList[18] = "K";
        atomicList[19] = "Calcium";
        valueList[19] = "Ca";
        atomicList[20] = "Scandium";
        valueList[20] = "Sc";
        atomicList[21] = "Titanium";
        valueList[21] = "Ti";
        atomicList[22] = "Vanadium";
        valueList[22] = "V";
        atomicList[23] = "Chromium";
        valueList[23] = "Cr";
        atomicList[24] = "Manganese";
        valueList[24] = "Mn";
        atomicList[25] = "Iron";
        valueList[25] = "Fe";
        atomicList[26] = "Cobalt";
        valueList[26] = "Co";
        atomicList[27] = "Nickel";
        valueList[27] = "Ni";
        atomicList[28] = "Copper";
        valueList[28] = "Cu";
        atomicList[29] = "Zinc";
        valueList[29] = "Zn";
        atomicList[30] = "Gallium";
        valueList[30] = "Ga";
        atomicList[31] = "Germanium";
        valueList[31] = "Ge";
        atomicList[32] = "Arsenic";
        valueList[32] = "As";
        atomicList[33] = "Selenium";
        valueList[33] = "Se";
        atomicList[34] = "Bromine";
        valueList[34] = "Br";
        atomicList[35] = "Krypton";
        valueList[35] = "Kr";
        atomicList[36] = "Rubidium";
        valueList[36] = "Rb";
        atomicList[37] = "Strontium";
        valueList[37] = "Sr";
        atomicList[38] = "Yttrium";
        valueList[38] = "Y";
        atomicList[39] = "Zirconium";
        valueList[39] = "Zr";
        atomicList[40] = "Niobium";
        valueList[40] = "Nb";
        atomicList[41] = "Molybdenum";
        valueList[41] = "Mo";
        atomicList[42] = "Technetium";
        valueList[42] = "Tc";
        atomicList[43] = "Ruthenium";
        valueList[43] = "Ru";
        atomicList[44] = "Rhodium";
        valueList[44] = "Rh";
        atomicList[45] = "Palladium";
        valueList[45] = "Pd";
        atomicList[46] = "Silver";
        valueList[46] = "Ag";
        atomicList[47] = "Cadmium";
        valueList[47] = "Cd";
        atomicList[48] = "Indium";
        valueList[48] = "In";
        atomicList[49] = "Tin";
        valueList[49] = "Sn";
        atomicList[50] = "Antimony";
        valueList[50] = "Sb";
        atomicList[51] = "Tellurium";
        valueList[51] = "Te";
        atomicList[52] = "Iodine";
        valueList[52] = "I";
        atomicList[53] = "Xenon";
        valueList[53] = "Xe";
        atomicList[54] = "Cesium";
        valueList[54] = "Cs";
        atomicList[55] = "Barium";
        valueList[55] = "Ba";
        atomicList[56] = "Lanthanum";
        valueList[56] = "La";
        atomicList[57] = "Cerium";
        valueList[57] = "Ce";
        atomicList[58] = "Praseodymium";
        valueList[58] = "Pr";
        atomicList[59] = "Neodymium";
        valueList[59] = "Nd";
        atomicList[60] = "Promethium";
        valueList[60] = "Pm";
        atomicList[61] = "Samarium";
        valueList[61] = "Sm";
        atomicList[62] = "Europium";
        valueList[62] = "Eu";
        atomicList[63] = "Gadolinium";
        valueList[63] = "Gd";
        atomicList[64] = "Terbium";
        valueList[64] = "Tb";
        atomicList[65] = "Dysprosium";
        valueList[65] = "Dy";
        atomicList[66] = "Holmium";
        valueList[66] = "Ho";
        atomicList[67] = "Erbium";
        valueList[67] = "Er";
        atomicList[68] = "Thulium";
        valueList[68] = "Tm";
        atomicList[69] = "Ytterbium";
        valueList[69] = "Yb";
        atomicList[70] = "Lutetium";
        valueList[70] = "Lu";
        atomicList[71] = "Hafnium";
        valueList[71] = "Hf";
        atomicList[72] = "Tantalum";
        valueList[72] = "Ta";
        atomicList[73] = "Tungsten";
        valueList[73] = "W";
        atomicList[74] = "Rhenium";
        valueList[74] = "Re";
        atomicList[75] = "Osmium";
        valueList[75] = "Os";
        atomicList[76] = "Iridium";
        valueList[76] = "Ir";
        atomicList[77] = "Platinum";
        valueList[77] = "Pt";
        atomicList[78] = "Gold";
        valueList[78] = "Au";
        atomicList[79] = "Mercury";
        valueList[79] = "Hg";
        atomicList[80] = "Thallium";
        valueList[80] = "Tl";
        atomicList[81] = "Lead";
        valueList[81] = "Pb";
        atomicList[82] = "Bismuth";
        valueList[82] = "Bi";
        atomicList[83] = "Polonium";
        valueList[83] = "Po";
        atomicList[84] = "Astatine";
        valueList[84] = "At";
        atomicList[85] = "Radon";
        valueList[85] = "Rn";
        atomicList[86] = "Francium";
        valueList[86] = "Fr";
        atomicList[87] = "Radium";
        valueList[87] = "Ra";
        atomicList[88] = "Actinium";
        valueList[88] = "Ac";
        atomicList[89] = "Thorium";
        valueList[89] = "Th";
        atomicList[90] = "Protactinium";
        valueList[90] = "Pa";
        atomicList[91] = "Uranium";
        valueList[91] = "U";
        atomicList[92] = "Neptunium";
        valueList[92] = "Np";
        atomicList[93] = "Plutonium";
        valueList[93] = "Pu";
        atomicList[94] = "Americium";
        valueList[94] = "Am";
        atomicList[95] = "Curium";
        valueList[95] = "Cm";
        atomicList[96] = "Berkelium";
        valueList[96] = "Bk";
        atomicList[97] = "Californium";
        valueList[97] = "Cf";
        atomicList[98] = "Einsteinium";
        valueList[98] = "Es";
        atomicList[99] = "Fermium";
        valueList[99] = "Fm";
        atomicList[100] = "Mendelevium";
        valueList[100] = "Md";
        atomicList[101] = "Nobelium";
        valueList[101] = "No";
        atomicList[102] = "Lawrencium";
        valueList[102] = "Lr";
        atomicList[103] = "Rutherfordium";
        valueList[103] = "Rf";
        atomicList[104] = "Dubnium";
        valueList[104] = "Db";
        atomicList[105] = "Seaborgium";
        valueList[105] = "Sg";
        atomicList[106] = "Bohrium";
        valueList[106] = "Bh";
        atomicList[107] = "Hassium";
        valueList[107] = "Hs";
        atomicList[108] = "Meltnerium";
        valueList[108] = "Mt";
        atomicList[109] = "Darmstadtium";
        valueList[109] = "Ds";
        atomicList[110] = "Roentgenium";
        valueList[110] = "Rg";
        atomicList[111] = "Copernicium";
        valueList[111] = "Cn";
        atomicList[112] = "Nihonium";
        valueList[112] = "Nh";
        atomicList[113] = "Flerovium";
        valueList[113] = "Fl";
        atomicList[114] = "Moscovium";
        valueList[114] = "Mc";
        atomicList[115] = "Livermorium";
        valueList[115] = "Lv";
        atomicList[116] = "Tennessine";
        valueList[116] = "Ts";
        atomicList[117] = "Oganesson";
        valueList[117] = "Og";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could make sure that you have a font that displays itself specifically at that size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. The code I pasted above creates a new font for every font size below a certain maximum.

Comment: It creates a new Font object. However, many fonts today are something like OpenType fonts which are constructed programmatically. Despite hinting, sometimes these fonts don't work perfectly. Originally, computer fonts were drawn from pixels by human beings. These fonts came in a variety of sizes, and you could only get the ones that that the creator had drawn. These fonts sometimes do better if the small sizes were included.

Comment: Do you know of any fonts that would work this way? Or would I have to make it myself?